# Fixed number of rows, with horizontal scroll for chips

Tags: flutter

I have tried using gridlist, flutter staggered grid view but was still not able to do it.
This is what I would like it to look like.
[Intended look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlyTi.png)

The best i could do is this, but the problem is that if i use a grid it gives each element same width.

```
GridView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: widget.profile.interests.length,
    gridDelegate:
    new SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
    maxCrossAxisExtent: 50,
    mainAxisSpacing: 10,
    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    childAspectRatio: 0.3),
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return CardWidget(context, index);
    })
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1atvT.jpg)

Comment: Please attached a code you have already tried

Comment: @LonelyWolf i have edited, with the code snippet

Comment: @GenchiGenbutsu if u see carefully in Intended look u will see that each item has its own width as defined by its text, however if u see in "output" u will see each item has a fixed size. Using a grid view i cannot do that

Comment: Do you want each row to slide separately or slide both rows together

Comment: @LonelyWolf Both rows slide together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ListView instead...

```
ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CardWidget('Long text'),
              CardWidget('Even longer text'),
              CardWidget('Long text'),
              CardWidget('Even longer text'),
              CardWidget('Text'),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              CardWidget('Text'),
              CardWidget('Short text'),
              CardWidget('Text'),
              CardWidget('Short text'),
              CardWidget('Long text'),
              CardWidget('Even longer text'),
            ],
          )
        ])
      ],
    );
```

OUTPUT
[image]

UPDATE WITH BUILDER

Here is another solution with builder. There is probably better solution for this. It just a first one what cross my mind

```
List<String> list = ['Long text', 'Even longer text', 'Long text', 'Even longer text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Short text', 'Text', 'Short text', 'Long text', 'Even longer text'];

SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return index.isEven ? CardWidget(list[index]) : Container();
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return index.isOdd ? CardWidget(list[index]) : Container();
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was exactly looking for. Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately still cannot figure out the logistics to use this with just one list of items. As in your case you have used 2 rows, hence 2 children. If i split my 1 list of items equally it wont we correct as one list might have more characters than the other which would lead to uneven 2 rows.

Comment: Do you want your rows to always to be even no matter the number of elements(ex: if there is only 2 one on top one on bottom)?

Comment: I amended my answer above to reflect every other element going in each row but if this is not what you want let me know

Comment: Suppose i have 10 items, ideally it would be 5 items in the top row and 5 in the bottom, but the problem with this is that suppose the bottom 5 items occupy more space (Because they have more characters) then it will look bad. so the split has to be bases on space they occupy (even it it be 6:4 or something). Wrap does a good job if i am not using a scroll.

Comment: My comment above is still applicable. As u are just splitting the list into 2 equal parts.

Comment: In updated part of my answer I'm not splitting the list... The list is only one. I then display odd indexes of that list in one row and even indexes in other row.. Please look at it carefully and try to understand it

Comment: You did not get a what I ment suppose, u have a list of 4 elements [Small(5), ALongWord(9), Pot(3), AnotherLongWord(15)]. What your code will do will split it into a list of 8 characters(5+3) & 24 char(13+15) as a result the 8 char text will occupy less space than the later. While what would have been nice was [Small, ALongWord, Pot] & [AnotherLongWord].

Comment: Well ok that is right but it would require a lot of programming to get what you want  which is impossible to fit it here so I'm sure no-one will make this code for you here. I would recommend you to look for some 3rd party packages or solutions on the web or start programming it by your self... I perhaps gave you a starting point and you can now extend it as you want

Answer (score 1):

```
List<int> topRow = [];
List<int> bottomRow = [];

  List<int> _addRowElements() {
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      if (i.isEven) {
        topRow.add(numbers[i]);
      } else {
        bottomRow.add(numbers[i]);
      }
    }
    return topRow;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ..._addRowElements()
                          .map(
                            (number) => TextAndIconWidget(
                              label: number.toString(),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      ...bottomRow
                          .map(
                            (number) => TextAndIconWidget(
                              label: number.toString(),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Is this what you where looking for?

Comment: I wanted a horizontal scroll, look at the output of the other answer