# Scrolling Wrap Widget With 2 lines and Variable Size Objects

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I cannot figure out how to create a Scrolling Wrap Widget inside my app that displays a number of items over 2 lines and is scrollable Horizontally to reveal the lines content:

```
return
 SafeArea(
   child: SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Wrap(
        direction: Axis.horizontal,
        runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        children:[
          for (var i=0;i<10;i++)  Card(
            elevation: 6,
            color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(title,),
            ),
          ),
        ]
    ),
),
 );
```

The result for this is :
[image]

I tired to wrap the Wrap with a Container with fixed height and every other combination imaginable and have not found a way to do this correctly, Basically I want to achieve a grid like functionality where the children are not all constrained to a fixed sized cell but are maintaining their variable width .

Expected result as requested would be a scroll-able list that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the expected result if possible?

Comment: I added a picture of what I expect my scrolling list to look like , and It would be dynamically sized , if possible, I imagine it has something to do with the Scroll View width being unbound in this case and thus not wrapping but what would be a way to achieve this with 2 lines and Variable Sized child widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Answer Will Help You.

```
List<String> list = ['Long text', 'Even longer text', 'Long text', 'Even longer text', 'Text', 'Text', 'Short text', 'Text', 'Short text', 'Long text', 'Even longer text'];

SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return index.isEven ? CardWidget(list[index]) : Container();
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
              child: ListView.builder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: list.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return index.isOdd ? CardWidget(list[index]) : Container();
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )
```

I refer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973744/fixed-number-of-rows-with-horizontal-scroll-for-chips) solution.

Output like this

[image]

Comment: Thank you , this truly does something similar to the target I had, would have never thought to do it like this. If someone else has ideas on how this could be achieved linearly and somewhat responsive I am open to it , but I will accept this answer and thank you for this simple elegant solution.

Comment: The only issues this has is that it does seem slow, and there is an odd look when one of the items i really oversized like say an item in the second column that has 5x size of the average item, so if anyone has any suggestions on how to get the widgets size dynamically during build and split the lists according to this instead , It would get me the end result I want.

Answer (score 1):

I was have similar problem and I fixed with constrained box. And can you try this;

```
 return SingleChildScrollView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  child: ConstrainedBox(
    constraints: BoxConstraints(
      maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
      maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.5,
    ),
    child: Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
      alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
      spacing: 10,
      runSpacing: 2,
      children: List.generate(
        myList.length,
        (index) {
          return ChoiceChip(
              onSelected: (bool isSelected) {
                 //when selected it works code
                
              },
              label: SizedBox(
                height: 20,
                child: Text(name),
              ),
              selected: false);
        },
      ).toList(),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution for me